# Launch an activity on clicking the notification when app is in background or is completely closed

Tags: android

I am creating a taxi app. Whenever a passenger requests for a ride, the request is processed by server and a taxi driver is notified. Driver app contains an activity with alarm which will start ringing on receiving the FCM notification. FCM works well when the app is in foreground but it doesn't launch the alarm activity when the app is in background or is in closed state. Is there any way to start the intended pending intent from notification even if app is in background.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alert)
            .setContentTitle("Firebase Push Notification")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `BroadcastReciever` for this purpose.

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "");
    wl.acquire();


    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

    intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(context, Test.class); //Test is a dummy class name where to redirect
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra("msg","Task Pending");
    context.startActivity(intent);
    wl.release();
}
```

and in your Test Activity ring the alarm as you like.

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {

private Ringtone r;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);
    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, notification);
    r.play();

    ImageView buttonCancelAlarm = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.buttonCancelAlarm);

    buttonCancelAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cancelAlarm(Test.this);
            finish();
        }
    });

}
public void cancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    r.stop();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 12345, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}
```

i hope it helps.